How to tune the function of line-to operation `|-` and `-|` in TikZ?
I was plot the flowchart as below with the MWE:
\documentclass[border=8pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         cap = round,
         every rectangle node/.style = {draw,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=2cm},
         empty/.style = {circle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt}]
        \node[rectangle] (A) {input $x$};
        \node[empty] (B) [right=1 of A] {};
        \node[rectangle] (C) [above right=.3 and 3 of A] {$\frac15x$};
        \node[rectangle] (D) [below right=.3 and 3 of A] {$x+4$};
        \node[empty] (E) [right=5.5 of A] {};
        \node[rectangle] (F) [right=1.5 of E] {output};
        \node[empty] (F1) [below=1.2 of F] {};
        \node[empty] (F2) [below=1.2 of A] {};
        \draw[-latex] (A) -- (B) |- node [empty,sloped,pos=.75,above=-.2] {$x\ne1$} (C);
        \draw[-latex] (B) |- node [empty,sloped,pos=.75,below=-.2] {$x=1$}  (D);
        \draw[-latex] (C) -| (E) (D) -| (E) -- (F);
        \draw[-latex] (F) -- (F1) -- node[empty,sloped,below=-.2] {$x<99$} (F2) -- (A);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}


However, I found that the Horizontal and Vertical Lines Operation |- and -| reached a limited function as the document below shown:

In my above code: I have the following three questions:
\draw[-latex] (A) -- (B) |- node [empty,sloped,pos=.75,above=-.2] {$x\ne1$} (C);
\draw[-latex] (B) |- node [empty,sloped,pos=.75,below=-.2] {$x=1$}  (D);
\draw[-latex] (C) -| (E) (D) -| (E) -- (F);
\draw[-latex] (F) -- (F1) -- node[empty,sloped,below=-.2] {$x<99$} (F2) -- (A);


the code above of FOUR \draw of FOUR arrows is a little superfluous, but the arrow is based on \path
Is there any tune of my code to avoid defining the node of (B) and (E) explicitly in my case, what I want is a more powerful |- and -| provide a parameter such as proportion=<fp in 0~1> which decide the horizonal/vertical length of the conjunction automatically
In the framework of TikZ, is there exists better solution to plot flowchart like this without immersed in multiple seperate \path operation?



For the first: you can remove the 3 ;\draw[-latex] in between. For the second point Have a look ext.paths.ortho library tikz-ext documentation

@pascal974 Thanks to your reply,if I remove the ; \draw[-latex] all the paths will be only one, thus there remains only one arrow in the end. And I will consult for the tikz-ext's documentation.

I'm not sure I answer your question, but we can simplify the code with ext.paths.ortho
Edit: With zarko's answer to this post How can I create TikZ annotations with arrows and braces for parts of a formula?, we can replace \draw [arr] (F) --++(0,-1.5cm) -| (A) by \draw [arr] (F) r-du [du distance=1.5cm] (A)
\documentclass[border=8pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  ext.paths.ortho
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  cap = round,
  rectangle/.style = {
      draw,
      outer sep=0pt,
      minimum width=2cm},
  %  empty/.style = {
  %     circle,
  %     inner sep=0pt,
  %     outer sep=0pt,
  %     minimum size=0pt},
  arr/.style = {-latex},
  lib/.style = {pos=#1,font=\small},
]
  % 
  \node[rectangle] (A) {input $x$};
  \node[rectangle] (C) [above right=.3 and 3 of A] {$\frac15x$};
  \node[rectangle] (D) [below right=.3 and 3 of A] {$x+4$};
  \node[rectangle] (F) [right=7 of A] {output};
  %%%%%%%%
  \draw [arr] (A) -|- (C) node[lib=0.875,above]{$x\ne1$};
  \draw [arr] (A) -|- (D) node[lib=0.875,below]{$x=1$};
  \draw [arr] (C) -|- (F);
  \draw [arr] (D) -|- (F);
  %\draw [arr] (F) --++(0,-1.5cm) -| (A) node[lib=0.25,below]{$x<99$};     
  \draw [arr] (F) r-du [du distance=1.5cm] (A) node[lib=0.5,below]{$x<99$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}



Excellent Tuning, and the tikz-ext did provide powerful extensions to TikZ, I will spare some time reading the docs, thanks!

I edited the answer.
